# Inheritance substitute for method parameters in Go

Tags: oop, inheritance, go

I understood that Go has no inheritance and works with composition.

Here is my small example:

```
type Car struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"response"`
    // some properties coming from a XML file
}

type Audi struct {
    Car
    // some more properties coming from a XML file
}

func UnmarshalFromXML(url string, car *Car) { /* fill the properties from the XML file */ }
```

What I actually want:

```
var audi Audi
UnmarshalFromXML("someURL", &audi)
```

But this does not work, because there is no inheritance. But I need structs to use the unmarshal functionality for XML files.

So what to do?

Comment: By the way, if you have a problem where you're dealing concretely with XML and using `encoding/xml` to do the unmarshaling, then your function signature should look like this `UnmarshalFromXML(url string, car interface{}) error`.

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance in `go` very different from another languages. When a type extended from a parent type, the two types remain distinct. The solution in your case is to create an interface, and pass interface as parameter in the function. Take a look to the example below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// creating an interface
type Vehicle interface {
    Move()
}

type Car struct {
    Color string
    Brand string
}

// Car has method Move(), automatically stated implement Vehicle interface
func (c *Car) Move() {
    fmt.Print("Car is moving")
}

func(c *Car) Honk() {
    fmt.Print("Teeeet... Teet")
}

type Audi struct {
    EngineType string
    Car
}

// passing an interface
func UnmarshalFromXML(url string, v Vehicle) { 
    fmt.Print(v)
    v.Honk() 

}


func main() {
    var car = Car{Color:"Green"}
    var audi = Audi{}
    audi.Car = car
    audi.Brand = "Audi"
    audi.EngineType = "EC"

    UnmarshalFromXML("someURL", &audi)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ZO4P_3fjmz

This article have a great explanation of OOP in `go`: http://spf13.com/post/is-go-object-oriented/

Answer (score 1):

You could try using interfaces instead

```
    type Car interface {
       theCar()
    }

    type CarBase struct {
    }

    func (_ CarBase) theCar() {
    }

    type Audi struct {
      CarBase
    }

    func UnmarshalFromXML(url string, car Car)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, because we need some attributes for the XML unmarshalling.

Comment: @MichaelDorner, what prevent you from adding the properties to the class?

Comment: As far as I understood there is no inheritance in Go with classes.

Comment: There is no inheritance but you can add properties to base class or subclass and will be fine. I do it all the time with JSON.